# How to add NSDictionary of dictionaries to NSArray?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries. This is the structure of my main dictionary:

```
The content of dictionary(
        {
        mondaysSales=     {
        totalSale = "1234.99";
    },
        tusdaySales= {
        totalSale = "1234.99";
    },
        wednesdaySale={
        totalSale = "1234.99";
    },
        thursdaySale{
        totalSale = "1234.99";
    },
        fridaySale{
        totalSale = "1234.99";
    }
)
```

but I want to add each day with the day key to a array. For example:

this would be one of the entries of the array:

```
        fridaySale{
        totalSale = "1234.99";
    }
```

Any of you how can accomplish this?, I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: It looks like you have an array of Dictionaries...

Comment: What Jacky Boy says -- you have an array of one-element dictionaries.  You probably need to fix the code creating that.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the dictionary and add it to the array. Note that dictionaries are not sorted and you probably won't end up with a correct order for your weekdays

```
NSMutableArray *array = [@[] mutableCopy]
for (NSString* key in dictionary) {
    id value = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    [array addObject:value];
}
```

Comment: in this case I would get only this {
        totalSale = "1234.99";
    } loosing the day of the week

Comment: 2 things. 1) `[dictionary allKeys]` 2) another is the fact that what the op has is not a dictionary, but an `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a new object type and add that to the array?

StorageObject.h:

```
@interface StorageObject:NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *day;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *saleType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *saleValue;
@end
```

StorageObject.m:

```
@implementation StorageObject
@synthesize
day = _day,
saleType = _saleType,
saleValue = _saleValue;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_day release];
    [_saleType release];
    [_saleValue release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Now just loop through your NSDictionary using:

```
for(NSString *key in [dictionary1 allKeys])
{
    NSDictionary *innerDictionary = [dictionary1 objectForKey:key];

}
```

For every dictionary returned in that loop, instantiate your custom storage object and add it to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a dictionary of dictionaries:

You can do

```
NSMutableArray *list = [@[] mutableCopy]; 

for (NSString *key in [mainDictionary allKeys]) {
    NSDictionary *dict =  @{ 
                        key :  [mainDictionary objectForKey:key],   
                           };
    [list addObject:dict];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out solution:

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[tempDict setObject:[mainDic objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
[myArray addObject:tempDict];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do this just don't create an NSDictionary and instead create an NSArray, by doing the following

```
NSArray *Array = @[@{@"friday sale, totalSale" : @"1234.99"}]
```

Or if you want to have specifics gotten from anything else in it.

```
NSInteger value = 1;
NSArray *Array = @[@{ @"Friday sale, totalSale" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)value]}];
```

Then you get this value from simply saying,

```
NSString *somestring = Array["Friday sale, totalSale"];
```